# NanoHTTPD stopped when I play games

Tags: android, nanohttpd

I have an android application that starts a server NanoHTTPD. The problem happens when I start the server, I leave the application in the background, and I start playing a game or a heavy application. After a few minutes the server is stopped. How I can keep the server started, even playing games or using other applications? (like AirDroid)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll get killed by the Android system unless you place it into a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and make it a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

Comment: Glad I could help. Had a similar issue a year or two ago.